# Formatting text in the with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I created a table with HTML, but I want my text in each row to be at the top of each cell and not at the center. Please help if you have a solution

I expected the text to be at `top: 0` of each cell but it's just at the center

Comment: Please include your code so far as a [mre]

Comment: `table > tbody > tr > td { vertical-align: top; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align: top;` does the magic for you.

Check the below example

```css
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```